# СтОглазоногая или стАглазоногая?

Tags: орфография

Есть фраза: "Чего-нибудь, способного подкрепить силы населения Станции, уставшего от поедания биомассы и всяких «грибруктов Убегающей Стаглазоногой Несильносиликоидной квазиберёзы» из оранжерейной столовки."

Как лучше - "стОглазоногая" или "стАглазоногая"?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **стоглазоногая.** Сравнить: **столетие, стократный, стокилограммовый.**

При образование сложного слово здесь используется форма "СТО".

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Думал, что будут другие мнения, исходя из того, что существует, скажем, профессиональное - "стасильный агрегат". Но нет, видимо, вы полностью прАвы.

Comment: В словарях нашел только СТОСИЛЬНЫЙ:
 
СТОСИЛЬНЫЙ, стосильная, стосильное (тех.). В сто лошадиных сил. Стосильный мотор. Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935 1940 …

е хавел